# Elastic APM Service map not showing links properly

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, go, spring-cloud-gateway, apm

Golang application calls Nodejs Microservice application through a Gateway springboot cloud gateway.

All applications have apm enabled.

Golang code

```
var tracingClient = apmhttp.WrapClient(http.DefaultClient) 
 tracingclient.Do(req.WithContext(ctx))
```

Currently the service map is showing
Golang application-> Gateway springboot cloud gateway
Golang application-> Nodejs Microservice application

What it should be
Golang application -> Gateway springboot cloud gateway -> Nodejs Microservice application

When I look at the transaction, the parent.id the same for gateway springboot gateway and nodejs microservice

**Golang application**

- trace.id: 3797d96d7c3d8b961d354a220331b746
- transaction.id: 3797d96d7c3d8b96

**Gateway springboot cloud gateway**

- trace. id: 3797d96d7c3d8b961d354a220331b746
- parent.id: 591a6edc2d918245
- transaction.id: a7d74e023fbfc861

**Nodejs Microservice application**

- parent.id: 591a6edc2d918245
- trace.id: 3797d96d7c3d8b961d354a220331b746
- transaction.id: 46eb85fdea9e88d8

The gateway is likely passing whatever there is to the Nodejs Microservice application hence they have the same parent
How can i change that so that the parent.id different?

Thank you in advance